# ReferenceError: "$" is not defined in <eval>

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to call a javascript function from java code.

This is my java code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
  ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
  // read script file
  engine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("f:/workspace/timsnew/WebContent/js/ipam/report_utils.js"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

  Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
  // call function from script file
  inv.invokeFunction("generatePdf", "abc@gmail.com","cloudInstanceProvisioningTemplAudit","cloudInstanceProvisioningTemplAuditGrid","Cloud Instance Provisioning Template Audit","a3","l","shahzad","hussain");
  
}
```

This is my JavaScript code

```js
function generatePdf(email_id,reporttype,gridId,mailsHeading,pagesize,pageformat,contact_first_name,contact_last_name){ 

  //var source=('#'+gridId)[0];
  //**loadingPopup**("Sending Email to the selected contact."+'<br><br>'+"Please Wait...");
  tableToJson(**$**('#'+gridId).get(0),mailsHeading,pagesize,pageformat,contact_first_name,contact_last_name);
}
```

I am also getting error for loadingPopup is not defined.

Below error is seen

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined in <eval> at line number 558
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have JQuery referenced in your html page?

Comment: It seems like jQuery is not available to your javascript.

Comment: Well, did you define `$`? It's probably JQuery that defines this (in many cases) so did you load that library?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.
I am relatively new to this method. Can you please explain how to load the JQuery library when calling the function from java code?

Answer (score 0):

So in that case use vanilla javascript. You should replace this:

```
** $ ** ('#' + gridId).get(0)
```

with:

```
document.querySelector('#' + gridId)
```

I am not familiar with this Java syntax, but previous snippet is equivalent to `$('#' + gridId).get(0)` when jQuery is loaded.